Use types as constants within switch()?
I have some types in a checkoutTypes.ts file like so:
export type CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection = "InvoiceAddress";
export type CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection = "DeliveryAddress";
export type CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection = "DeliveryAndReview";

export type CheckoutSection = CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection | CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection | CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection;

In a function in a different file I want to use these for case matching in a switch() statement:
import type { CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection, CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection, CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection, CheckoutSection } from "~/types/checkoutTypes";

interface Props {
  identifier: CheckoutSection,
}
const props = defineProps<Props>();

const isSectionCompleted = computed(() => {
  switch (props.identifier) {
    case CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection:
      return checkoutStore.getActiveSection !== CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection;
    case CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection:
      return checkoutStore.getActiveSection === CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection;
  }
});

However, I'm getting the following error: ReferenceError: CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection is not defined. on the case CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection line.
Are type definitions not suitable to be used for comparison with a variable, or am I missing something else?

TypeScript does not exist at runtime, the metadata (including all of those type definitons) is stripped out in transpilation to JavaScript because it is not JavaScript. So no, you can't use it in any way at runtime including as a switch case.

@jonrsharpe I was expecting typescript to transpile those to constants, but I guess I'm wrong. Any Idea how I can use them both as constants and type definitions without essentially doubling the code?

Perhaps an enum, they exist at runtime. Or just use those constants: https://tsplay.dev/mMPp6N

Could you give me an eample of how this would look with an enum in my example? didn't manage to get it to work yet.

@jonrsharpe If I use constants according to your example, would it be valid to still keep them in a ts file solely purposed of providing types, even if its neither a type nor an interface?

As @jonrsharpe already mentioned, TypeScript does not exist at runtime. You could export your values as constants and get the types you want from them like this:
export const CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection = "InvoiceAddress";
export const CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection = "DeliveryAddress";
export const CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection = "DeliveryAndReview";

export type CheckoutInvoiceAddressSectionType = typeof CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection;
export type CheckoutDeliveryAddressSectionType = typeof CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection ;
export type CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSectionType = typeof CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection ;

export type CheckoutSectionType = CheckoutInvoiceAddressSectionType | CheckoutDeliveryAddressSectionType | CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSectionType;

Now we can access both the values and the types
import { CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection, CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection, CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection, CheckoutSectionType } from "~/types/checkoutTypes";

interface Props {
  identifier: CheckoutSectionType,
}
const props = defineProps<Props>();

const isSectionCompleted = computed(() => {
  switch (props.identifier) {
    case CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection:
      return checkoutStore.getActiveSection !== CheckoutInvoiceAddressSection;
    case CheckoutDeliveryAddressSection:
      return checkoutStore.getActiveSection === CheckoutDeliveryAndReviewSection;
  }
});

You might also be interested in enums. const enum is transpiled into constant values, so you can actually do such things:
const enum EDirection {
  Up,
  Down,
  Left,
  Right,
}

// Using the enum as a parameter
function walk(dir: EDirection) {}

walk(EDirection.Left);

